# redux thunk fetch api action and reducer

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

So decided to use `redux-thunk` and I have a problem to write a function in my actions and reducer. Actually function looks like this:

```
  async getData() {
    if (this.props.amount === isNaN) {
      return;
    } else {
      try {
        await fetch(
          `https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=${this.props.base}`,
        )
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            const date = data.date;
            const result = (data.rates[this.props.convertTo] * this.props.amount).toFixed(4);
            this.setState({
              result,
              date,
            });
          }, 3000);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
      }
    }
  }
```

Also I already have action types

```
export const FETCH_DATA_BEGIN = 'FETCH_DATA_BEGIN';
export const FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_DATA_FAIL = 'FETCH_DATA_FAIL';
```

and actions like this

```
export const fetchDataBegin = () => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.FETCH_DATA_BEGIN,
  };
};

export const fetchDataSuccess = data => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
    data: data,
  };
};

export const fetchDataFail = error => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.FETCH_DATA_FAIL,
    error: error,
  };
};
```

And then comes the hard part for me where I don't know how to get the same result from function `async getData()`. I already have just this in my action :

```
export async function fetchData() {
  return async dispatch => {
    return await fetch(`https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=${this.props.base}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
         // <------------------- WHAT NEXT?
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export function fetchData() {
  return dispatch => {
    fetch(`https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=${this.props.base}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => dispatch(fetchDataSuccess(data)), e => dispatch(fetchDataFail(e)))
  }
};
```

Now this code:

```
const date = data.date;
const result = (data.rates[this.props.convertTo] * this.props.amount).toFixed(4);
this.setState({
  result,
  date,
});
```

goes into your reducer

```
if(action.type === FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS) {
  const date = action.data.date;
  const rates = action.data.rates;
  return { ...state, rates, date };
}
```

Now you can use the redux state in your component and make the rest of the calculations there (ones that need `this.props`).

To dispatch the `fetchData` action now, you do `this.props.dispatch(fetchData())` in your react-redux connected component.

**EDIT**

Here's how you use the state in the component.

I'm assuming you have created the redux store. something like:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer,applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Now, you can use the `react-redux` library's `connect` function to connect the redux state to your component.

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return { 
    date: state.date,
    result: (state.rates[ownProps.convertTo] * ownProps.amount).toFixed(4);
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    fetchData: () => dispatch(fetchData())
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent)
```

You can use this Higher Order Component in your DOM now and pass the appropriate props to it:

```
import ConnectedComponent from "./pathTo/ConnectedComponent";
...
return <View><ConnectedComponent convertTo={...} amount={...} /></View>;
```

And, also inside `YourComponent` you can now read `this.props.date` and `this.props.result` and use them wherever you need to.

You might want to look at [selectors](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) in the future to memoize the state and reduce the performance cost of redux.

Comment: Can u also write how to use redux state in component to do those calculations?

Comment: Sure thing! Sorry, it was nighttime where I live, had to go. I'll edit the answer and show the state usage code

Comment: Thank you very much Giorgi! Can I ask you about similar problems in future? It looks you have knowlage about that ;)

Comment: You're welcome! I'd love to help anyone who needs it, whenever I can find time.

Comment: Well I did what u wrote to me and it almost work! Now i have NaN problem. Have u time to help me figure this out?

Comment: I'll be off work in about two hours, so go ahead and add a new question with details and I'll check it out later, if anyone else doesn't answer first.

Comment: So when you got some time check here if there would be no asnwer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565762/nan-problem-with-react-redux-and-react-thunk